# Declaring variables in functions that are called more than once in int main() (in C)

Tags: c, function, variables, counter, declaration

As stated in the title, I am dealing with a function that is called in main more than once, it's purpose is to count the vowels in an array of characters and the results are correct only the first time it gets called. After that instead of starting from zero, it picks up the counting from where it left off, leading to incorrect results.

This is the function:

```
int function(char *pointer, int num_of_elements)

{
    int i=0;
    if (num_of_elements==0) return i;
    if ((*pointer== 'a') || (*pointer== 'A') || (*pointer== 'e') || (*pointer== 'E') || (*pointer== 'i') || (*pointer== 'I' )||( *pointer=='o') || (*pointer =='O') || (*pointer== 'u') || (*pointer== 'U')) {i++;}
    pointer++;
    num_of_elements--;
    return function(pointer,num_of_elements);
}
```

The pointer points to the array of characters and the variable i is the counter.

Comment: I'm surprised that this works the first time.  You're doing this recursively, which is a bit odd, but not preserving the current value of `i` from call to call.  I would have expected `return (i+function(pointer, num_of_elements));`

Comment: @intersomnium is there any specific (maybe purely academic) reason why you are using recursion (function calling itself)?  If not then this is a major crime ;)

Comment: Yep, that was it, the i was missing in return, thank you. :)

Comment: It worked the first time because in my actual function I wrote static int i; but when posting the question here I forgot to write the static part..

Comment: @gollum hahah, yes, there is. It's specified so in an exam problem.

Comment: @intersomnium I'm relieved to hear that ;)

Comment: When posting a question, don't rewrite it.  Copy and paste the exact program text.  It prevents typos and is much faster.

Comment: @dbush lesson learned. Will do so in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the sum of `i`and the result of your recursive call of `function`. Adapt your code like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int function(char *pointer, int num_of_elements)
{
    if (num_of_elements==0)
        return 0;

    char c = tolower( *pointer );
    int i = ( c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' ) ? 1 : 0;
    pointer++;
    num_of_elements--;
    return i + function( pointer, num_of_elements );
}
```

I recommend to solve your probelem with in a loop and to use function `tolower`:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int function(char *pointer, int num_of_elements)
{
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_of_elements; i++, pointer ++)
    {
       char c = tolower( *pointer );
       if ( c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' )
           count ++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: I'm dealing with an exam problem where it's specified that the function must be recursive, otherwise yes I love the second solution. The first one has some yet to be discovered elements in it (for me), since I'm a beginner in C, but I will keep it in mind. Thank you. :)